# c++ how to pass an array to function inside function

Tags: c++, arrays

Following is some example code, I know how to pass an array to function_2 directly. now my question is how should I pass an array to function_2 which is inside the function_1, and what are the parameters should be in function_1 as I marked below. 
I appreciated for any help.

```
void function_2(int ***array)
{
    //do something with array
}

void function_1(/* what should be */)
{
    function_2(/* what should be */);
}

int main()
{
    int ***array;
    function_2(array);

    function_1(array);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need an `int ***`? Also, in C++ one should generally use `std::vector` or `std:array` instead of raw arrays. Much simpler.

Comment: There is no use for int* as an array in C++.

Comment: An int *** is not the same as a native array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may pass it directly using the same multi-level pointer type, where the pointer is simply passed by value.  However, you must also pass the size of the dimensions of the array, since a primitive array does not store that information internally.  Otherwise, inside the function you would have no way of knowing how big the array is.  `std::size_t` is the best type to indicate the size of a data structure.

```
void function_2(int ***array, std::size_t pages, std::size_t cols, std::size_t rows)
{
    //do something with array
}

void function_1(int ***array, std::size_t pages, std::size_t cols, std::size_t rows)
{
    function_2(array, pages, cols, rows);
}
```

However, you shouldn't do this.  Unless you *absolutely* have to use a primitive array, **then don't**.  Use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead.  It stores the size internally, so you don't have to pass multiple parameters.  `vector` also offers a wide variety of other improvements and safety checks.  It is the standard alternative to primitive arrays in C++.

Here is how you might use a three-dimensional vector of ints:

```
void function_2
(std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > &myVector)  // pass by reference
{
    /* do stuff */
}

void function_1
(std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > &myVector)  // pass by reference
{
    function_2(myVector);
}

int main()
{
    std::size_t pages = /* num */;
    std::size_t cols = /* num */;
    std::size_t rows = /* num */;

    std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > myVector
            (pages, std::vector< std::vector<int> >(cols, std::vector<int>(rows, 0)));

    function_2(myVector);

    function_1(myVector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type `int***` needs to stay consistent, so the parameter for function one should be `int ***array`, and you should call function two like so: `function_2(array)`.

Full code:

```
void function_2(int ***array)
{
    //do something with array
}

void function_1(int ***array)
{
    function_2(array);
}

int main()
{
    int ***array;
    function_2(array);

    function_1(array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful send a pointer as parameter in your function. Why don't you use vector instead?

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> function_2(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> array)
{
    //do something with array
    return array;
}

std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>  function_1(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> array)
{
    function_2(array);
    return array;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> array;
    function_2(array);
    function_1(array);
}
```